# dict.get() giving TypeError

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm getting a TypeError when using the dict.get() function. Below is an example of the input:

```
input_data = {
    "level1": [
        {
            "level2": [
                {
                    "hn": "hn_example1",
                    "mi": ["mi1"]
                },
                {
                    "hn": "hn_example2",
                    "mi": ["mi2"]
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
}
```

When using the standard [] extraction, the result is as expected:

```
for output in input_data["level1"][0]["level2"]:
    print(output)

>> {'hn': 'hn_example1', 'sv': ['sv1']}
>> {'hn': 'hn_example2', 'sv': ['sv2']}
```

But when using .get(), it gives a TypeError:

```
for output in input_data.get(["level1"][0]["level2"], []):
    print(output)
```

> TypeError: string indices must be integers

Can anyone explain why this is? I was under the impression that dict.get() returns the same result as dict[], except in the case where the key doesn't exist, in which case it would return the default value (in this case an empty list). An in any case `type(input_data["level1"][0])` returns a dict, not a string.

Just a note that `print(input_data.get(["level1"][0]["level2"], []))` gives the same result, it's just that in this usecase I need to access the values one at a time.

Comment: That's not how get works. You're not passing the keys and indexes (you _can't_, that syntax doesn't exist), you're making a list then indexing into it then trying to access a key on the result.

Comment: The only value you can meaningfully pass to `input_data.get()` is `"level1"`, as that's the only key that dictionary has.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the rapid responses! Sorry I'm a bit new to Python, and don't quite follow the explanations - would you be able to explain in a bit more detail?

Comment: Well note the [mre] is just `["level1"][0]["level2"]`. The get method is never even called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [get method](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/dictionary/get) is a method of python dictionary. Its input is key and (optional) value that should be return if key does not exist.

`[]` Is another syntax for accessing dictionary values. You can think of it as another method of dictionary (in real it calls `__getitem__` method).

So when you write `input_data["level1"]` you get value for key `"level"` which is list so you use result of it as list

```
mylist = input_data["level1"] # it returns list
first_el = my_list[0] # this is dict again!
level2 = first_el["level2"] # and list again
# it's the same as input_data["level1"][0]["level2"]
```

Saying that, you could replace all dictionary accesses with `get` call

```
mylist = input_data.get("level1")
first_el = my_list[0] # this is list and have no get method
level2 = first_el.get("level2")
# it's the same as input_data.get("level1")[0].get("level2")
```